# ElasticSearch Ingest pipeline parsing error for .xls

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm getting the following exception whenever I post a .xls document to Elastic Search with pipeline=attachment in only one environment.  The other environments with the exact same version of the ingest plugin 6.6.11 or higher are able to successfully create/index the document.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "exception",
        "reason" : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ElasticsearchParseException[Error parsing document in field [data]]; nested: NoSuchFileException[/tmp/elasticsearch.X8YIXwqv/apache-tika-1557338864100513463.tmp];",
        "header" : {
          "processor_type" : "attachment"
        }
      }
    ],
    "type" : "exception",
    "reason" : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ElasticsearchParseException[Error parsing document in field [data]]; nested: NoSuchFileException[/tmp/elasticsearch.X8YIXwqv/apache-tika-1557338864100513463.tmp];",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "ElasticsearchParseException[Error parsing document in field [data]]; nested: NoSuchFileException[/tmp/elasticsearch.X8YIXwqv/apache-tika-1557338864100513463.tmp];",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "Error parsing document in field [data]",
        "caused_by" : {
          "type" : "no_such_file_exception",
          "reason" : "/tmp/elasticsearch.X8YIXwqv/apache-tika-1557338864100513463.tmp"
        }
      }
    },
    "header" : {
      "processor_type" : "attachment"
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

Comment: Restarting the ES cluster fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to the /tmp directory on the server and create the sub-directory elasticsearch.xxxxx cited in the exception or restart ES node then verify if the sub-directory has been created.  I believe that apache tika 1.17 is attempting the create a temp file parsing the .xls file and obviously fails because the sub-directory missing